# Mongo query: field contains other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

given doc1:

```
{ object1: {} }
```

and doc2:

```
{ object1: { object2: {} }
```

i’d like to do a query to return doc2 but not doc1 - i want to query for docs that have something(anything) in a given field ?

edit for clarification:

i want to query for docs that have anything in a given field ?
doc2 has some value, different than {} for object1

Comment: The query is this for MongoDB: `"object1.object2": { $exists: true }`

Comment: This will also work: `{ object1: { $ne: { } } }`.

Comment: `"object1.object2": { $exists: true }` - this is valid but i might not have been clear enough. i want to return the doc if it has any field set, not just "object2".
`{ object1: { $ne: { } } }` does not appear to work

Answer (score 0):

```
db.myCollection.findOne( {"$where": function() { return obj.object1 && Object.keys(this.object1).length > 0 }} )
```

The initial `obj.object1 &&` means it exists and it is there to prevent errors when the field is missing